# How to suppress display of escape sequences in diff

Tags: git

When I run git diff to see what was changed in a modified file, diff displays many highlighted escape sequences. For example:

```
ESC[1mindex a7671ab..c228e2c 100644ESC[m
ESC[1m--- a/core/bp-nav-horizontal.phpESC[m
ESC[1m+++ b/core/bp-nav-horizontal.phpESC[m
ESC[36m@@ -77,7 +77,7 @@ESC[m
 <!-- Contact Us -->ESC[m
   <ul>ESC[m
       <li>ESC[m
```

How can I suppress these `ESC[xxx` characters. They make it very hard to read the text.

**Amended 15 Aug 2014**

This is not really about git diff. Displays of git log also show the `ESC...` characters. This seems like a configuration problem, but I don't know where it is. Where should I look?

Answer (score 18):

The problem is with the pager used by GIT to print diffs and logs. Adding -R to the configuration for less solved the problem for me. I used

```
git config --global core.pager "less -R"
```

Comment: This worked best for me (and made the color functionality work)--thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You might have set color.ui=always (or `auto` and the terminal detection does not work). You can turn it off with `never` (if it is `always` try `auto` first).

You can configure all commands with `config.ui` or specific for git-diff with `color.diff`.

```
git config --global color.ui never
```

Use

```
git config --local -l
git config --global -l
git config --system -l
```

To list the current settings for the project, user and machine. To switch it temporarily on/off you can use the `--color=always` argument at each command. For example:

```
git log --color=never
```

See also: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration

Answer (score 0):

Git 2.14.x/2.15 (Q3 2017) will finally respect `git config color.ui never`.

See [commit 11b087a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/11b087adfd469ca597f1d269314f8cad32d0d72f), [commit 18fb7ff](https://github.com/git/git/commit/18fb7ffc3dc9df081c241d6b7105b4058d5746d3), [commit d75dfb1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d75dfb1089d471501f6042341bed647525f6e293), [commit d8b6868](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d8b68686a4cc8a486823dd356ed4dba0e51536ea), [commit 136c8c8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/136c8c8b8fa39f1315713248473dececf20f8fe7), [commit ab7ded3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ab7ded34d6a9a5d4c8bf073cb9627b8054f430cf), [commit 29ef53c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/29ef53cd361e8751f9f2f40811af0ce863e449b6), [commit aa8a5d1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aa8a5d144da4e4ec43580831ff4a741538d21db4), [commit 18a2565](https://github.com/git/git/commit/18a2565016d45538345a06cd9b912040b5581fc1), [commit bf285ae](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bf285ae6dbfa8e2b847940e6ad987ff3cbe40712), [commit 4a68e36](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4a68e36d7d106abaf44e3ac960276145b5a25723), [commit 51331aa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/51331aad69a1d89a8b6d1ff82bb5fedbdb6ccc6a), [commit 097b681](https://github.com/git/git/commit/097b681baac3a5e9455c74e3072a458249691e40), [commit 5d3d068](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5d3d0681abb8f2bc2383ee7660cf2b02e89cdd07), [commit 2eda010](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2eda0102beb85b97bd43708176d81feabaf161e8) (13 Jul 2017) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 15595ce](https://github.com/git/git/commit/15595ce438d0ce8b195187f00663baa407a2d024), 11 Aug 2017)</sup>

> "`%C(color name)`" in the pretty print format always produced ANSI
>   color escape codes, which was an early design mistake.
>   They now honor the configuration (e.g. "`color.ui = never`") and also tty-ness
>   of the output medium.

Answer (score 0):

I am on a system that does not have 'less' installed by default.

I use:

- git config --global core.pager "/usr/bin/more -v"

You could also choose:

- git config --system core.pager "/usr/bin/more -v"

The key point is that it is not 'git', but the (default) configuration of the pager you use.